# Flutter: Update Widgets On Resume?

Tags: dart, flutter

In Flutter, is there a way to update widgets when the user leaves the app and come right back to it? My app is time based, and it would be helpful to update the time as soon as it can.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can listen to lifecycle events by doing this for example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final AsyncCallback? resumeCallBack;
  final AsyncCallback? suspendingCallBack;

  LifecycleEventHandler({
    this.resumeCallBack,
    this.suspendingCallBack,
  });

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    print("state changed ${state.name}");
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        if (resumeCallBack != null) {
          await resumeCallBack!();
        }
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
        if (suspendingCallBack != null) {
          await suspendingCallBack!();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}



class AppWidgetState extends State<AppWidget> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(
      LifecycleEventHandler(resumeCallBack: () async => setState(() {
        // do something
      }))
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, can you add a WidgetsBindingObserver to a StatelessWidget? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, but what do you want to do when such a lifecycle event happens?

Comment: What that occurs, I would like to call `dispatch` for my `StoreConnector`, a handful of widgets below

Comment: You can put above code everywhere. It doesn't have to be inside a widget. That was just an example.

Comment: Can you provide me a complete example because your code seems to be broken

Comment: @CodeGeek I think yeah it's kinda broken when you try and call the suspend and resume methods.

Comment: Yeah, so what can be done? Also, we cannot use this method when we change page and want something to be done when we come back to the same page.

Comment: Where is FutureVoidCallback defined? I can't find it in the flutter package source and google is not helping either?

Comment: @ChrisCrowe you are right. You need to declare it yourself. `typedef FutureVoidCallback = Future<void> Function();`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do I need to add observer to every widget or is it enough to have it at the top level, I was looking for something similar to Appdelegate (iOS)

Comment: @anoop4real top-level is enough.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Lets say if I have a multiple paged app, does every page separately need to have an observer?

Comment: No, only in the App widget. @anoop4real

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is it possible to find app kill state? (app kill/app close)

Comment: I'm not fully up-to-date on this topic currently, but I guess not. The recent changes regarding persisting of UI state (scroll position and similar) seems to be to pass it to the Android-side of the app on every change so that in case the app is closed Android can persist the state without reaching out to Flutter. When the app is killed only sync code can be executed, and calling out to Flutter only works async.  Simon Lightfoot gave a speech recently at the Flutter-Vikings conference about that topic and this is how I understood it.

Comment: just be aware, resume is called every time you call `showDialog(...)` as well

Comment: Great answer, but this doesn't remove the observer in the `dispose()` method
It is good practice to do it with `WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);`

Comment: @Jack' it's definitely good practice. In this case I omitted it because it should stay registered until the app exits so removing doesn't make much difference in this case, but definitely good to always clean up.

Answer (score 29):

Using system Channel:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg){
  debugPrint('SystemChannels> $msg');
  if(msg==AppLifecycleState.resumed.toString())setState((){});
});
```

`

Comment: This may be obvious to others, but it took me a while to figure out I needed to move this to a location after the Flutter runApp call.

Comment: do we put this code into initState()? The systemChannels will act like a listener to listener to the change of lifecycle?

Comment: What is the type of the msg variable? Why is it not of type AppLifecycleState?

Comment: @edhubbell from the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBinding/instance.html)
`If you need the binding to be constructed before calling runApp, you can ensure a Widget binding has been constructed by calling the WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() function.`

Comment: This is a good solution, unfortunately if you set the handler for these channels to your own implementations, you will no longer receive notifications for `WidgetsBindingObserver`, as they rely on these message handlers to work. For instance, `didChangeAppLifecycleState` will no longer be called.

Answer (score 27):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class LifecycleWatcherState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        onResumed();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        onPaused();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        onInactive();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        onDetached();
        break;
    }
  }

  void onResumed();
  void onPaused();
  void onInactive();
  void onDetached();
}
```

**Example**

```
class ExampleStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleStatefulWidgetState createState() => _ExampleStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleStatefulWidgetState
    extends LifecycleWatcherState<ExampleStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  void onDetached() {

  }

  @override
  void onInactive() {

  }

  @override
  void onPaused() {

  }

  @override
  void onResumed() {

  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the way to do. Still one question: return null; in Widget build() is no more allowed. How to solve this?

Comment: @cwhisperer you can use SizedBox() instate of null or remove the "Widget build(BuildContext context)" I didn't test it but maybe it will not make a problem.

Comment: This seems to roughly be the approach the lifecycle package takes: https://pub.dev/packages/lifecycle

Answer (score 19):

Simple way:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

handleAppLifecycleState() {
    AppLifecycleState _lastLifecyleState;
    SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg) {
      
     print('SystemChannels> $msg');

        switch (msg) {
          case "AppLifecycleState.paused":
            _lastLifecyleState = AppLifecycleState.paused;
            break;
          case "AppLifecycleState.inactive":
            _lastLifecyleState = AppLifecycleState.inactive;
            break;
          case "AppLifecycleState.resumed":
            _lastLifecyleState = AppLifecycleState.resumed;
            break;
          case "AppLifecycleState.suspending":
            _lastLifecyleState = AppLifecycleState.suspending;
            break;
          default:
        }
    });
  }
```

just add `handleAppLifecycleState()` in your `init()`

**OR**

```
class AppLifecycleReactor extends StatefulWidget {
      const AppLifecycleReactor({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _AppLifecycleReactorState createState() => _AppLifecycleReactorState();
    }
    
    class _AppLifecycleReactorState extends State<AppLifecycleReactor> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      AppLifecycleState _notification;
    
      @override
      void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
        setState(() { _notification = state; });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Text('Last notification: $_notification');
      }
    }
```

For more details you refer [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html)

Answer (score 18):

For deeply testing, I think the results are worth for read. If you are curious about which method you should use, just read the below: (Tested on Android)

There are three methods for LifeCycle solution.

1. `WidgetsBindingObserver`
2. `SystemChannels.lifecycle`
3. [flutter-android-lifecycle-plugin](https://github.com/blackmenthor/flutter-android-lifecycle-plugin)

The main difference between `WidgetsBindingObserver` and `SystemChannels.lifecycle` is that `WidgetsBindingObserver` have more capables If you have a bunch of widgets that need to listen LifeCycle. `SystemChannels` is more low layer, and used by `WidgetsBindingObserver`.

After several testing, If you use `SystemChannels` after `runApp`, and home widget mixin with `WidgetsBindingObserver`, home widget would be failed, because `SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler` override the home's method.

So If you want to use a global, single method, go for `SystemChannels.lifecycle`, others for `WidgetsBindingObserver`.

And what about the third method? This is only for Android, and If you must bind your method **before** `runApp`, this is the only way to go.

Comment: If `SystemChannels.lifecycle` is used then `WidgetsBindingObserver` callbacks are not received.

Comment: Plus one for detail

Answer (score 6):

Here’s an example of how to observe the lifecycle status of the containing activity ([Flutter for Android developers](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-listen-to-android-activity-lifecycle-events)):

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class LifecycleWatcher extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LifecycleWatcherState createState() => _LifecycleWatcherState();
}

class _LifecycleWatcherState extends State<LifecycleWatcher> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  AppLifecycleState _lastLifecycleState;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      _lastLifecycleState = state;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_lastLifecycleState == null)
      return Text('This widget has not observed any lifecycle changes.', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);

    return Text('The most recent lifecycle state this widget observed was: $_lastLifecycleState.',
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(Center(child: LifecycleWatcher()));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Solutions implemented for detecting onResume event using "WidgetsBindingObserver"
OR "SystemChannels.lifecycle" works only when App is gone in background completely like during lock screen event or during switching to another app. It will not work if user navigate between screens of app. If you want to detect onResume event even when switching between different screens of same app then use visibility_detector library from here : https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector

```
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return VisibilityDetector(
    key: Key('my-widget-key'),
    onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
      num visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;
      debugPrint(
          'Widget ${visibilityInfo.key} is ${visiblePercentage}% visible');
      if(visiblePercentage == 100){
                debugPrint("Resumed !");
              }
    },
    child: someOtherWidget,
  );
}
```

Comment: it solved my problem, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the answer by @Gunter to use with Riverpod. Any widget that watches the lifecycle provider will be rebuilt on state change.

*lifecycle_state_provider.dart*

```
class LifecycleStateNotifier extends Notifier<bool> {
  @override
  bool build() {
    final lifecycleEventHandler = LifecycleEventHandler._(ref);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(lifecycleEventHandler);
    return true;
  }

  void updateState(val) {
    state = val;
  }
}

final lifecycleProvider = NotifierProvider<LifecycleStateNotifier, bool>(() {
  
  return LifecycleStateNotifier();
});

class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  Ref ref;
  LifecycleEventHandler._(this.ref);

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
         ref.read(lifecycleProvider.notifier).updateState(false);
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
         ref.read(lifecycleProvider.notifier).updateState(true);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

*main.dart*

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(child: MainApp()),
  );
}

class MainApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    bool inBackground = ref.watch(lifecycleProvider);
    print('inBackground: $inBackground - build called');
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Github](https://github.com/bigbott/lifecycle_riverpod)

If you don't interested of updating widgets, but rather just want to know in which state (background/foreground) app is now, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76502092/2534191).

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute onResume method but only in one page you can add this in your page:

```
var lifecycleEventHandler;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ///To listen onResume method
    lifecycleEventHandler = LifecycleEventHandler(
        resumeCallBack: () async {
          //do something
        }
    );
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(lifecycleEventHandler);
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    if(lifecycleEventHandler != null)
      WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(lifecycleEventHandler);

    super.dispose();
  }
```

and having LifecycleEventHandler class as the first answer of this post:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final AsyncCallback resumeCallBack;
  final AsyncCallback suspendingCallBack;

  LifecycleEventHandler({
    this.resumeCallBack,
    this.suspendingCallBack,
  });

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        if (resumeCallBack != null) {
          await resumeCallBack();
        }
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        if (suspendingCallBack != null) {
          await suspendingCallBack();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reliable `onOpen` handler,
you should call it both from `initState`
and as in [WidgetsBindingObserver docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html).

Tested with:

- The first start of the app.
- Tap any system button (Back, Home, Recent apps) to close the app,
  then open the app again.

Code:

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    onOpen();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) onOpen();
  }

  void onOpen() {
    debugPrint('-------- OPEN --------');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```