# Flutter send local notification by API in background

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, background-fetch

I have an API that I'm checking, and when the response changes I need to send a notification to the user. I would like to know how to do this without FCM Push Notifications.

I'm using `flutter-local-notifications` and background fetch (https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch) to do it. On the background fetch docs it says that background fetch will do your function once every 15 minutes, which is good enough for me.

This is my `initPlatformState()`:

```dart
Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
  // Load persisted fetch events from SharedPreferences
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String json = prefs.getString(EVENTS_KEY);
  if (json != null) {
    setState(() {
      _events = jsonDecode(json).cast<String>();
    });
  }

  // Configure BackgroundFetch.
  BackgroundFetch.configure(
          BackgroundFetchConfig(
            minimumFetchInterval: 15,
            stopOnTerminate: false,
            enableHeadless: true,
            forceReload: true,
            startOnBoot: true,
          ),
          _onBackgroundFetch)
      .then((int status) {
    print('[BackgroundFetch] SUCCESS: $status');
    setState(() {
      _status = status;
    });
  }).catchError((e) {
    print('[BackgroundFetch] ERROR: $e');
    setState(() {
      _status = e;
    });
  });

  // Optionally query the current BackgroundFetch status.
  int status = await BackgroundFetch.status;
  setState(() {
    _status = status;
  });

  // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
  // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
  // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
  if (!mounted) return;
}
```

I'm assuming that what's in the function that gets called in the fetch isn't needed for the question.

I tried this on my phone and simulator, and I used Xcode -> Simulate Background Fetch and it ran properly. It also ran properly when I opened the app. Unfortunately, it didn't run after 15 minutes. Is there something I'm missing?

How would I change my code to make the background fetch to happen every 15 minutes?

Comment: If you solve your problem please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523281/scheduling-different-notifications-on-each-day-flutter

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I spent lot of time trying to solve this but was not successful so I switched, I guessed what you are trying to do is to handle your own notification without Firebase or from an API like me, well this is it, after my search I was able to do this with the help of work manager package. So easy to use and implement, try it.

https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Comment: Wow I'm surprised that lots of people are having the same question! I honestly don't remember what I did with this, so I can't really test that. Thank you for the answer though, hopefully it will help other users coming to this question

Comment: Could you please send me the example code snippet to achieve what is described?  @SheshankS

Comment: @Habnarm Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523281/scheduling-different-notifications-on-each-day-flutter

Comment: @Jasurbek I wish I could but I don't remember/know where my code for all this is

Comment: This is a bad solution. Workmanager fetches every 15 minutes MINIMUM. That is unacceptable for a real time chat app.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer of @Habnarim suggested I have used [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) with [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to implement local notifications in the background.

Generally, I followed [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/background-local-notifications-in-flutter/), so it can be referred to for more details, but the code there is a bit outdated. I have fixed some discrepancies and also put everything related to notifications in a separate library.

1. Add workmanager, flutter_local_notifications and cupertino_icons to project.
2. Add the below permission inside the 'manifest' tag

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`
3. Add the below permission inside the 'application' tag

   ```
         <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.
                        ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action 
                    android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                    <action 
               android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
   ```
4. Add code:

*notifications.dart*

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';

//  Workmanager  input data:
const _uniqueName = 'whatevername_1';
const _taskName = 'whatevername_2';
Duration? _frequency; // = Duration(minutes: 15); // cannot  be  less

_calculateFrequency() {
  // some logic here, db connection etc.
  return Duration(minutes: 15);
}

// Notifications plugin input data
const _channelId = '1234';
const _channelName = 'whatever_name';
const _channelDescription = 'whatever_description';
const _notificationTitle = 'probably just App name';
String _message = 'default  message'; //if message is always the same make const

_createMessage() {
  // some logic here, db connection etc.
  return 'Hello from my app!';
}

void initLocalNotifications() async {
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    return;
  }
  _frequency = await _calculateFrequency();
  Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher,
      isInDebugMode: true); //TODO change  debug mode
  Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
    _uniqueName,
    _taskName,
    frequency: _frequency,
  );
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifPlugin =
        new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var ios = new DarwinInitializationSettings();

    var settings = new InitializationSettings(iOS: ios, android: android);
    notifPlugin.initialize(settings);
    _showNotificationWithDefaultSound(notifPlugin);
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

Future _showNotificationWithDefaultSound(notifPlugin) async {
  _message = await _createMessage();

  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      _channelId, _channelName,
      channelDescription: _channelDescription,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high);
  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new DarwinNotificationDetails();

  var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
  await notifPlugin.show(
      0, _notificationTitle, _message, platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Default_Sound');
}
```

*main.dart*

```
void main() async {
   initLocalNotifications();
    runApp(
    const ProviderScope(child: MainApp()),
  );
}
```

5. Run on the device in debug mode
6. On the device allow notifications for the app: long press app icon-> App info -> Notifications: allow everything except led light.

I have tested the above on an Android device and it kinda works. I.e. when the app is in the background notifications appear.

Two problems. First, I don't want to show notifications when the app is in the foreground. It [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835039/how-do-i-check-if-the-flutter-application-is-in-the-foreground-or-not) but the solution seems to be too complex.
Second, notifications do not appear when the app is forced to quit. My guess is that users of low-end devices remove apps from memory frequently. So, currently, I think, that I will use push notifications instead.