# flutter didChangeAppLifecycleState never runs

Tags: flutter, dart

I implemented the `WidgetsBindingObserver`, but the app is NEVER sent to the background so it doesn't recognize the `AppLifecycleState.resumed`

this is the current implementation

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    print('\n\ndidChangeAppLifecycleState');
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('\n\nresumed');
        _mymethod();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print('\n\ninactive');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print('\n\npaused');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        print('\n\ndetached');
        break;
    }
  }
```

to simulate the process i do the next in android

1. run the project as --release
2. open the widget with the `WidgetsBindingObserver`
3. open another app (like chrome or phone settings)
4. return to the app

when returning to the app i can see my widget on screen, the app doesn't restart, but NONE of the prints appears on the console not event the `print('\n\ndidChangeAppLifecycleState');` and `_mymethod();` is never executed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) mixin requires a bit more work than merely implementing the interface. You also need to add the following to your widget state class:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: i totally missed that, i will read carefully next time the documentation, thank you