# How to detect current timestamp when a user leaves a screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Chat application with Flutter, i need to detect the time and date when a user leaves the screen of a particular chat. In other words, I need a way to detect the actual time a user navigates from the chat screen to any other screen. Please is there any solution for this? I was able to find a plugin called Route Observer, but from what I've read in the documentation, it can't really solve my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can get timestamp `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch` when the user pops the chat screen.

Comment: Did you try `AppLifecycleState.inactive`?

Comment: Please can u show me a code snippet? How do I detect when a user pops the screen.. I'm pretty new to Flutter

Comment: There is no "one way" of doing things in programming. Please post your current code so we can advise you what the best way to do it in your code is.

Comment: [Check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641554/flutter-didchangeapplifecyclestate-never-runs) Try to use `AppLifecycelState` detect user leaving current page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Navigator.push()` to go to the chat screen, you can use the `then()` method which is called when you leave the screen i.e. pop the context.
Simply call `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch` in the `then()` method.

Comment: Thanks.. This is really helpful