# How to show notification on receiving the event from pusher in flutter?

Tags: flutter, notifications, chat, pusher

I am implementing the pusher chat in the flutter application it is working fine I can send the event and receive the event from the pusher debug console.
But now I am facing an issue when I received the event from the pusher console I want to show the notification if the app is in the foreground or in the background anyone has any idea. kindly suggest

Comment: This might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835039/how-do-i-check-if-the-flutter-application-is-in-the-foreground-or-not

Comment: Anton Volkov thanks for replying but it doesn't show me what I asked I want to show notification when I receive event from pusher

Comment: Are you using Pusher Channels or Pusher Beams?
How are you currently handling receipt of the event in your app?

Comment: I am using pusher channel and when I try to send an event from pusher console I receive it and also popups the notification as I have used flutter local notification but I don't receive notification when I am in other screen or app is closed kindly ellabora

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?