# How to blur Flutter app when it's inactive

Tags: flutter

What’s the best way to blur a Flutter app when is not active?
The similar way like iOS is doing with the Camera app.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to detect when the app is about to go into the background and take action just before it does. I have not tested this, but theoretically, you could apply a filter view over your app or maybe even redirect so that the OS screenshot for multitasking captures the blurred screen instead of whatever the user was on when they exited the app.

Comment: @daddygames Tested it, it doesn't work for the first time the app goes inactive/paused (while the app does get blurred, it shows it momentarily, it goes back to normal) however all the other times you open the app drawer the app gets blurred.

Comment: @daddygames I'm detecting it by `AppLifecycleState.inactive`. It works on iOS, but doesn't work on Android. Do you have a better way of detecting?

Comment: I cannot attest to the capabilities available here. This post might be helpful for covering both Android and iOS => [How do I check if the Flutter application is in the foreground or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52890987/3224608)

There is always the option to do this in the native code of each platform as well.

Comment: Exactly, that’s how I’m checking it. I guess, the problem on Android is that it triggers inactive too late and is not able to override it on time

Comment: I've described here the exact problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594245/why-in-applifecyclestate-inactive-state-widgets-are-not-redrawn-every-time

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for doing the same and here is the solution I've implemented.

[Demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7w4C.gif)

I used the Overlay widget to add the blur effect and use the AppLifecycleState to show it or not. Look at the code snippet below.
(and thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43552634/15694111) for the background blur effect code snippet)

You can find working demo [here](https://github.com/NicolasJacquet/backgroud_app_blurred)

```
MaterialApp(
  ...,
  builder: (BuildContext builderContext, Widget? child) => Overlay(
    initialEntries: <OverlayEntry>[
      OverlayEntry(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AppLifecycleOverlay(),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

```
class AppLifecycleOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppLifecycleOverlay({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AppLifecycleOverlay> createState() => _AppLifecycleOverlayState();
}

class _AppLifecycleOverlayState extends State<AppLifecycleOverlay>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool shouldBlur = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      shouldBlur = state == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
          state == AppLifecycleState.paused;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (shouldBlur) {
      return BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 8, sigmaY: 8),
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.grey.shade200.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using this code and testing in Android, this code is partially work.

It work when i swipe down the control center and go to setting. 

But when i click home / recent app button, the ui doesn't update.

I have been search in internet and have conclude may be it because flutter not render widget in state paused. Anyone have idea ?

ps : FLAG SECURE in android work, but i want to enable screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I have used an alternative approach in a `MaterialApp`, since my `HomeWidget` was not built/loaded if `builder:` field is present directly in the app widget when loaded from the `home:` (field of the `MaterialApp`).

Additionally, I am using a `FutureBuilder` to fetch some settings beforehand. The `AppLifecycleOverlay` is the same.

```dart
// main.dart
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Some Awesome App',
      // ...
      home: FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>(
        future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
          switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  HomeWidget(title: 'Some Awesome App', prefs: snapshot.data),
                  Overlay(initialEntries: [
                    OverlayEntry(builder: (BuildContext context) => const AppLifecycleOverlay()),
                  ])
                ]
              );
            default:
              return const Center(child: Text("Loading..."));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

The Overlay