# How can I tell if the app is in the background?

Tags: flutter

It happens in a DataBase is Locked error, and I would like to know when the application has no background;

I did some research on the internet, however, no result for Flutter.

Comment: Is it something like this your looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835039/how-do-i-check-if-the-flutter-application-is-in-the-foreground-or-not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.