# How to calculate the time a widget is in view in flutter

Tags: flutter

Coming from an Android background, I could calculate the time in the `onPause` and `onResume` and take them away from each other. How would I do this using flutter. I can get the time in the `initState` but not sure what method to call when the widget goes out of view. I'm using the `DateTime` class to calculate the time. Have I the right approach? Or...My use case is I want to reward a user staying on a screen.

Comment: For what purpose would you need that?

Comment: sorry just added

Comment: need to find time spent on screen

Comment: Would you not rather want to know if the application is in the foreground and/or if a specific route is active?

Comment: a specific route...I want to reward as user for staying on a screen(watching a video)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869873/flutter-update-widgets-on-resume/49870276#49870276 for app lifecycle and https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html for route

Answer (score 0):

You could get the time before and after navigating to the other widger:

```
    ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Second'),
          onPressed: () {
            print('First out: ${DateTime.now()}');
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondView()),
            ).then(
              (value) => print('First in: ${DateTime.now()}'),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Or (for StateFull) get the time on InitState() and on Dispose(), but there may be an delay when getting the time on dispose(). Depends on the precision that you need:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('Second in: ${DateTime.now()}');
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('Second out: ${DateTime.now()}');
    super.dispose();    
  }
```