# listen to device notification permission using Flutter notification_permissions package

Tags: flutter, dart-async

I am using the Flutter notification_permissions package.

I can retrieve the device notification permission status asynchronously by calling:

`PermissionStatus p = await NotificationPermissions.getNotificationPermissionStatus()`

However, I do not want to do this just once. I want to listen to the notification status as a stream, so that when it changes I can respond accordingly in my UI.

I tried the following:

```
NotificationPermissions.getNotificationPermissionStatus().asStream().listen((PermissionStatus s) {
    print('Notification permissions: $s');   
}
```

However, this stream does not emit events when I change the notification settings on the device.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I have achieved my desired functionality by creating a stateful widget that listens to the AppLifecycleState. I then call my async function whenever the app resumes to check the status of notification settings.

More info here: [Flutter: Update Widgets On Resume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869873/flutter-update-widgets-on-resume)