# Detect when we moved back to previous page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

We moved from Page1 to Page2 but now from Page2 we move back again to Page1 like this:

`Navigator.of(context).pop();`

How can we detect on Page1 that we went back?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869873/flutter-update-widgets-on-resume

Comment: @Steve - The question is about navigating back from the activity within the same application, but not about coming back to the application. Your link is not valid in the context of the question.

Comment: Thank you. This comment was posted a long time ago and I didn't realize my mistake.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => NextPage(),
    ),
  ).then((_){
// Here you will get callback after coming back from NextPage()
// Do your code here
});
```

Comment: easy and clean. Thanks!

Comment: Life-saving. I was doing WidgetsBinding with an observer and other such stuff. Its so simple.

Comment: This works really well ♥️

Comment: Does not work with Web Browser Back (Chrome, 119)

Answer (score 9):

In your `Page1`, When you push `Page2` wait for it to pop

```
Future<void> _goToPage2() async {
  await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Page2(),
    ),
  );
  print("Page2 is popped");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another solution, which is more verbose but also more efficient if you push a lot of Routes from the same Widget, would be to create your own `NavigatorObserver`.

1- Create your `NavigatorObserver`

```
final routeObserver = MyRouteObserver();

class MyRouteObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  final Set<RouteAware> _listeners = <RouteAware>{};

  void subscribe(RouteAware routeAware) {
    _listeners.add(routeAware);
  }

  void unsubscribe(RouteAware routeAware) {
    _listeners.remove(routeAware);
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    for (var listener in _listeners) {
      listener.didPop();
    }
  }
}
```

2- Add it to your `MaterialApp`

```
  return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
...
```

3- Implement `RouteAware` in the Widget where you want to listen to Navigation events, and subscribe/unsubscribe to your `routeObserver`

```
class _TablePageState extends State<TablePage> implements RouteAware {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    //This method will be called from your observer
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {}

  @override
  void didPush() {}

  @override
  void didPushNext() {}
}
```