# Detect enter the page event Flutter

Tags: flutter

Do we have any event trigger when user enter the page.

I found [Navigator.push().then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59423954/detect-when-we-moved-back-to-previous-page-in-flutter).
But seen it's very unconvenient.

I want to have somethings like initState, but trigger every time user enter the page.
In IONIC(hybrid frame work) its name is [ionViewWillEnter](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/ionview+will+enter)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really more convenient than `Navigator.push().then()` but you could use a `RouteObserver` to detect the page changes.

### Code

For this example I am going to define 2 global variables:

```dart
final routeObserver = RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>>();
int count = 0; // Number of times you are entering the page
```

Then add `routeObserver` to your `MaterialApp.navigatorObservers`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  home: InitialPage(),
  navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
)
```

Finally, you will need to manage the subscription of your `routeObserver` to your page. For this you will have to use a `StatefulWidget` as your "enter on page" behavior will be defined thanks to the page's `State`:

```dart
class InitialPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<InitialPage> createState() => _InitialPageState();
}

class _InitialPageState extends State<InitialPage> with RouteAware {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    count++;
  }
  
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)!);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    super.didPopNext();
    // view will appear
    setState(() => count++);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text('You entered on this page $count times'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => OtherPage(),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Text('Press me'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basically what I am doing is incrementing the `counter` when instanciating the page thanks to `initState` (called when the page is added to the widget tree) and by registering the `routeObserver` to your view I will be able to increment my counter when my page is already in the widget tree with `didPopNext` (and using a `setState` to update my UI).

[You can try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=334838a4b94afb7635953a3060db56cc&null_safety=true)

Comment: Hi Guilaume Roux. This absolute is what i'm looking. But it's only work in the common case. With `Bottom navigation`, this widget alway on the top. So  it alway trigger `didPopNext` on the nav bar class. Can we make it trigger on child tab?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, this code also works if `InitialPage` is accessed from a BottomNavigationBar, here's a code sample you can try: https://dartpad.dev/?id=521018ad7a378640ee3da9169bf75d1f&null_safety=true

Comment: You are right. It work with `BottomNavigationBar`. I used [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar), that my problem, it didn't trigger the `didPopNext ` function. I will raise this issue to that library. If you know, can you point me what problem with that library?

Comment: I've never used this package so I have no clue why it does not trigger the method. Maybe it uses another route observer which overrides the previous one.

Comment: I known, it have their own navigatorObservers for each tab.