# Flutter release apk doesnt work - just white screen

Tags: android, flutter, apk, release

My app works perfectly in DEBUG mode. But when I create a release APK or run in release mode I get an only white screen after starting the app. After some trying, I detected that the problem is in method, that I call after runApp(); But what is the problem?

```
void handleAppLifecycleState() {
  SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg) async {
    if (msg == "AppLifecycleState.resumed") {
      await updateStatusBar();
    }
    return Future.value(msg);
  });
}
```

Comment: device, because it is impossible to run release on emu

Comment: Are you missing some Manifest permissions? Debug and Release builds use different AndroidManifest.xml files.

Comment: How do you detected that this one is the problematic method?

Comment: I did not miss some permissions in manifest. It was working before upgrading flutter. And this problem was detected randomly. I was commenting on some parts of code

Comment: Facing the same issue! Did you find a solution for the same?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: yes, I use the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869873/flutter-update-widgets-on-resume

Answer (score 2):

I thing your problem is your `gradle version`.
a was same problem and I solved it with change gradle version to `3.5.4`.

```
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4"
     ...

    }
```